# Assign values from a ListBox with an Action Button in Excel

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I want to write the current time next to a selected label in excel using a button and listbox. I have the button writing the static time and selecting the new cells just fine, but I cannot figure out how to get it to write the selected value from the listbox. Here is my current code.

```
Sub NOWTIME()
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now(), "h:mm:ss AM/PM")
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ListBox5
Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select
End Sub
```

It seems as if the Macro is not recognizing the selected value of the listbox.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name suggests the ListBox contains list items.  Each item has an index number.  You will need to tell your code which item in the list (presumably the user selected item) to use.

Essentially you have two options:
**ListBox1.Text** gives you the text of the currently selected item as a string or **ListBox1.ListIndex** gives you the integer index value of the selected item.
Note that the list numbering is zero-based i.e. starts at 0.

[Take a look at this tutorial for further info on use of the listbox](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/indepth-vb6-listbox-tutorial)